# Scipy.optimize can't iterate between given bounds. Works only for initial value

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, scipy-optimize

I built a model with the following codes and run with one example.
Scipy.optimize can’t iterate values between bounds. It works only with initial discount value=0. If you have any suggestions, I would appreciate them.

Example:

```py
import pandas

ornek_other_var = {'const1': [0],'const2': [1],'const3': [0],'const4': [0],
'const5': [1],'const6': [0], 'const7': [0],'const8': [1],'const9': [10]}
ornek_other_var=pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(ornek_other_var)
price = {'price': [80]}
price = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(price)
price = pandas.Series(price['price'].values, name='price')
```

Optimization Model:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
        
        
def objective(discount, sign=-1.0):
    return price.multiply((1-discount))*(1/(1+math.exp(-(237.72+0.6*ornek_other_var['const1']+
           0.8*ornek_other_var['const2'] -0.85*ornek_other_var['const3']
           -0.79*ornek_other_var['const4']+0.7*ornek_other_var['const5']
           +0.05*ornek_other_var['const6']-0.33*ornek_other_var['const7']
           +0.87*ornek_other_var['const8'] +0.05*ornek_other_var['const9']
           -3*(price.multiply((1-discount)))))))
        
# initial
n = 1
discount = 0
        
print('InitialObjective: ' + str(objective(discount)))
        
    
minimize(objective,discount,method='SLSQP',bounds=[(0., 0.2)],callback=callable)
    
# final objective
print('FinalObjective: ' + str(objective(discount)))
        
# print solution
print('Solution')
print('Discount = ' + str(discount))
print('Price = ' + str(price))
```

Output:

```py
>>> InitialObjective: 0    51.469212
Name: price, dtype: float64
FinalObjective: 0    51.469212
Name: price, dtype: float64
Solution
Discount = 0
Price = 0    80
Name: price, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I am not familiar with pickle functions. But do you mean to say that you want to minimize a function with a variable `x` and with the value of `x` you will also be calculating a prediction using the pickle function? and would also like to minimize this prediction? Or I understood you wrong?

Comment: Yes exactly, my goal is finding the best x value for max x*f(x).  X has boundaries [0,0.8] and optimization should try each x values and during that calculation that pickle result must also change by changing x value for reaching optimal result. But i couldnt find way out. F(x) like always works with the initial value x.

Comment: If somehow you could share a [example] or show your objective function and optimization results, maybe I could help you.

Comment: @MuhammadMohsinKhan , sorry for late answering, you can find the example as answer. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your current question and add the example in your question. As this example is not an answer, you can't post it as an answer. Apart from that, I will try to check your example and get back to you.

Comment: I tried the code you posted above. It actually runs for 2 iterations and gives the result of discount to be `0.2`. And the discount value is `64`.

Comment: thank you so much for your interest. However i didnt understand how you get discount value as 64. Do i print wrong results? @MuhammadMohsinKhan

Comment: I changed your starting `discount` value from 0 to 0.1 and ran your code again. Plus you are not printing your results correctly. I did it as `res = minimize(objective,discount,method='SLSQP',bounds=[(0., 0.2)],callback=callable)` then I print `print(res)` then you see that your function value comes out to be 64 and discount is 0.2. Does this solve your question? If it did let me know so that I can post this as an answer to this question.

Comment: Yes, when i change starting point as 0.1 for bounds, i get same results with you. but actual optimum solution for that objective function is must be 78.0447 indeed not 64. Additionally i didnt understand why 0 doesnt work for bound.

Answer (score 0):

The problem's solution is calculated with excel solver as below, but python code doesn't give the same result.

If objective function is designed in brief:

max revenue: price*(1-discount) * f(price*(1-discount))

subject to discount [0., 0.2]

```
> Optimal Solution: 
Max Revenue: 78.0447 
f(price*(1-discount)):0.99575 
discount:   0.020275
```